# Sneakers store UI challenge

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I have been coding for just under 6 months now. I've made many projects but I don't have a clue if I am writing good code. So I did this frontendmentor challenge which includes HTML CSS and JS. It's mobile responsive and a good all-round challenge. So could anyone please review this code. Tell me what I should work on or if I did things the wrong way. I would really appreciate it. Thanks in advance.

Here is the link to the project: https://wetransfer.com/downloads/2e391bd44ff77f080b80e5d394564dc220220104155231/a97871

This is the project but without images:

```js
// hamburger variables
const hamburgerMenu = document.getElementById('hamburger-menu');
const navigation = document.getElementById('nav');
const overlay = document.getElementById('overlay');
const mobileCloseButton = document.getElementById('mobile-close-button');

// counter variables
const counter = document.getElementById('amount-value');
const addButton = document.getElementById('add-button');
const removeButton = document.getElementById('remove-button');
counterValue = 0;

// prices variables 
const discountPrice = document.getElementById('discount-price');
const originalPrice = document.getElementById('original-price');

// img carousel variables
const thumbmails = document.querySelectorAll('#pic');
const largeImg = document.getElementById('large-img');
const arrowLeft = document.getElementById('arrow-left');
const arrowRight = document.getElementById('arrow-right');
let carouselLength = thumbmails.length;
let carouselPosition = 0;

// shopping cart variables
const cartButton = document.getElementById('cart-button');
const shoppingCartOverlay = document.getElementById('shopping-cart');
const itemList = document.getElementById('item-list');
const addToCartButton = document.getElementById('add-to-cart');
const checkoutButton = document.getElementById('checkout-button');
const emptyCartText = document.getElementById('empty-cart');

let itemAmount = 0;
let itemsInCart = 0;

// reset hamburger class
navigation.classList.remove('.hamburger-open');

// hamburger evnetlisteners
hamburgerMenu.addEventListener('click', () => {
  navigation.classList.add('hamburger-open');
  overlay.classList.add('overlay-open');
})

mobileCloseButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  navigation.classList.remove('hamburger-open');
  overlay.classList.remove('overlay-open');
})

// counter eventlisteners
addButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  counterValue++;
  counter.innerText = `${counterValue}`
  if (counterValue > 0) {
    discountPrice.innerText = `$${counterValue * 125}.00`
    originalPrice.innerText = `$${counterValue * 250}.00`
  } else {
    discountPrice.innerText = `$125.00`
    originalPrice.innerText = `$250.00`
  }
});

removeButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  counterValue--;
  counter.innerText = `${counterValue}`
  if (counterValue > 0) {
    discountPrice.innerText = `$${counterValue * 125}.00`
    originalPrice.innerText = `$${counterValue * 250}.00`
  } else {
    discountPrice.innerText = `$125.00`
    originalPrice.innerText = `$250.00`
  }
});

// img carousel logic
thumbmails.forEach(picture => {
  picture.addEventListener('click', () => {
    largeImg.src = `${picture.src.replace('.jpg', '-HR.jpg')}`
    thumbmails.forEach(picture => {
      picture.classList = "";
    });
    picture.classList.add('active-img');
  })
});

console.log(carouselPosition);

// img carousel mobile
arrowLeft.addEventListener('click', () => {
  console.log('left');
  if (carouselPosition > 0) {
    carouselPosition--;
    largeImg.src = `${thumbmails[carouselPosition].src.replace('.jpg', '-HR.jpg')}`
  } else {
    carouselPosition = carouselLength - 1;
    largeImg.src = `${thumbmails[carouselPosition].src.replace('.jpg', '-HR.jpg')}`
  }
  console.log(carouselPosition);
});

arrowRight.addEventListener('click', () => {
  console.log('right');
  carouselPosition++;
  if (carouselPosition < carouselLength) {
    largeImg.src = `${thumbmails[carouselPosition].src.replace('.jpg', '-HR.jpg')}`
  } else {
    carouselPosition = 0;
    largeImg.src = `${thumbmails[carouselPosition].src.replace('.jpg', '-HR.jpg')}`
  }
  console.log(carouselPosition);
});

// shopping cart event listener
cartButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  shoppingCartOverlay.classList.toggle('shopping-cart-open');
});

// add to cart event listener
addToCartButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  itemAmount = counterValue;
  if (itemAmount > 0) {
    itemsInCart++;
    const item = document.createElement('div');
    item.classList.add('cart-item-container');
    item.innerHTML = `
      <img src="${largeImg.src}" class="item-img">
      <div class="item-info-container">
        <p>Fall Limited Edition Sneakers</p>
        <p>$125.00<span> x ${itemAmount}</span><span class='bold'> ${itemAmount * 125}.00</span></p>
      </div>
      <i class="far fa-trash-alt" id="trash-item"></i>
    `
    itemList.insertBefore(item, itemList.children[1]);

    let deleteItemButton = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('#trash-item'));
    deleteItemButton.forEach(deleteButton => {
      deleteButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
        itemsInCart--;
        deleteButton.parentElement.parentElement.removeChild(deleteButton.parentElement);
        ItemAmount();
      });
    });
  }
  ItemAmount();
})

// remove from cart event listener
function ItemAmount() {
  console.log(itemsInCart);
  if (itemsInCart > 0) {
    checkoutButton.style.display = "flex";
    emptyCartText.style.display = 'none';
  } else {
    checkoutButton.style.display = 'none';
    emptyCartText.style.display = 'inline-block';
  }
}
```

```css
/* imports */

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Kumbh+Sans:wght@400;700&display=swap');

/* variables */

:root {
  /* colors */
  --primary-orange: hsl(26, 100%, 55%);
  --primary-pale-orange: hsl(25, 100%, 94%);
  --neutral-very-dark-blue: hsl(220, 13%, 13%);
  --neutral-dark-grayish-blue: hsl(219, 9%, 45%);
  --neutral-grayish-blue: hsl(220, 14%, 75%);
  --neutral-light-grayish-blue: hsl(223, 64%, 98%);
  --neutral-white: hsl(0, 0%, 100%);
  --neutral-black: hsl(0, 0%, 0%);
  /* fonts */
  --main-font: 'Kumbh Sans', sans-serif;
}


/* typography */

h1 {
  font-size: 2.6rem;
  line-height: 100%;
  color: var(--neutral-very-dark-blue);
  margin-bottom: 2.5rem;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  color: var(--neutral-very-dark-blue);
  margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
}

h3 {
  color: var(--primary-orange);
  opacity: 75%;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 0.8rem;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

h4 {
  color: var(--neutral-grayish-blue);
  text-decoration: line-through;
  margin-bottom: 1.8rem;
}

p {
  color: var(--neutral-dark-grayish-blue);
  margin-bottom: 1.6rem;
  line-height: 160%;
}


/* resets */

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: var(--main-font);
}

body {
  background-color: var(--neutral-white);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

ul,
ol {
  list-style: none;
}


/* general styles */

img {
  width: 100%;
}

.page-container {
  width: 90%;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: var(--neutral-dark-grayish-blue);
  font-size: 1rem;
}


/* header styles */

header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  border-bottom: solid 1px var(--neutral-grayish-blue);
}

.left-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.logo-container {
  margin-right: 5rem;
}

.logo-container i {
  display: none;
}

nav {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

ul {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

ul li {
  margin: 0 1rem 0 1rem;
  padding: 2rem 0;
  position: relative;
  transition: ease-in-out 200ms;
  cursor: pointer;
}

ul li:hover {
  font-weight: 700;
}

ul li:hover::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 4px;
  background-color: var(--primary-orange);
}

.right-container {
  padding: 1rem;
}

.account-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
}

.cart-icon-container {
  margin-right: 2rem;
}

.cart-icon-container img {
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  aspect-ratio: 1;
}

.shopping-cart-overlay {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: var(--neutral-white);
  top: 4rem;
  left: -250px;
  width: 350px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 2.5rem 60px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.137);
}

.shopping-cart-content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0.5rem 1rem 1.5rem 1rem;
}

.shopping-cart-header {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  border-bottom: 1px solid var(--neutral-grayish-blue);
}

.shopping-cart-header h4 {
  margin: 1.5rem 0 1.5rem 2rem;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: var(--neutral-very-dark-blue);
}

.shopping-cart-content p {
  margin: 2.5rem 0;
  color: var(--neutral-grayish-blue);
  font-weight: bold;
}

.shopping-cart-overlay.shopping-cart-open {
  display: inline-block;
}

.checkout-button {
  display: none;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 95%;
  border: none;
  background-color: var(--primary-orange);
  border-radius: 5px;
  transition: ease-in 200ms;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.checkout-button h4 {
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 0.8rem 0;
  margin: 0;
  color: var(--neutral-white);
}

.checkout-button:hover {
  background-color: rgb(209, 87, 31);
}

.cart-item-container {
  padding: 1rem 0;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.cart-item-container img {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.item-info-container p {
  width: fit-content;
  margin: 0;
}

.bold {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: var(--neutral-very-dark-blue);
}

.cart-item-container i {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.account-container>img {
  height: 50px;
}

#mobile-close-button {
  display: none;
}

.overlay {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: var(--neutral-black);
  opacity: 75%;
}


/* header mobile responsive*/

@media screen and (max-width: 375px) {
  .page-container {
    width: 100%;
  }
  header {
    border: none;
  }
  nav ul {
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: flex-start;
  }
  nav ul li {
    padding: 1rem 0;
    margin: 0 2rem;
  }
  nav ul li a {
    font-weight: 700;
    color: black;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
  }
  .hamburger-open {
    background-color: var(--neutral-white);
    display: inline-block;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 75%;
    height: 100vh;
  }
  .overlay-open {
    display: inline-block;
  }
  #mobile-close-button {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 1.7rem;
    padding: 2rem 0 3rem 2rem;
    color: var(--neutral-dark-grayish-blue);
  }
  nav {
    display: none;
  }
  .right-container {
    padding: 1rem;
  }
  .left-container {
    padding: 1rem;
  }
  .account-container>img {
    height: 40px;
  }
  .shopping-cart {
    margin-right: 1rem;
  }
  .logo-container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 0;
  }
  .logo-container i {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 0.5rem;
    font-size: 1.4rem;
  }
}


/* main content styles */

.main-content-container {
  margin-top: 5rem;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.img-gallary-container {
  width: 50%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.img-gallary {
  width: 55%;
}

.large-img {
  position: relative;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.arrow-left {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 200px;
  left: 20px;
  background-color: var(--neutral-white);
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  display: none;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.arrow-right {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 200px;
  right: 20px;
  background-color: var(--neutral-white);
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  display: none;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.large-img img {
  border-radius: 1rem;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}

.smaller-images {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.smaller-images img {
  width: 5rem;
  flex-basis: 5rem;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin-top: 1rem;
}

.smaller-images img:hover {
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.active-img {
  border: 4px solid var(--primary-orange);
}

.smaller-images>img:not(:last-child) {
  margin-right: 1rem;
}

.product-info-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  width: 50%;
}

.product-info {
  width: 60%;
}

.price-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.price {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.discount {
  color: var(--primary-orange);
  background-color: var(--primary-pale-orange);
  padding: 0.3rem 0.6rem;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
  margin-left: 1rem;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.buttons-container {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.amount-buttons {
  display: flex;
  margin-right: 1rem;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 40%;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: var(--neutral-light-grayish-blue);
}

.amount-buttons h2 {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 1rem;
}

.amount-buttons button {
  font-size: 1rem;
  padding: 0.8rem;
  border-radius: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  color: var(--primary-orange);
  transition: 300ms ease-in-out;
}

.amount-buttons button:hover {
  background-color: var(--neutral-grayish-blue);
  opacity: 50%;
}

.amount-buttons button:active {
  background-color: var(--neutral-grayish-blue);
  opacity: 100%;
}

.add-to-cart-button {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 60%;
  border: none;
  background-color: var(--primary-orange);
  border-radius: 5px;
  transition: ease-in 200ms;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.add-to-cart-button:hover {
  background-color: rgb(209, 87, 31);
}

.add-to-cart-button h4 {
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 0 0 0 1rem;
  color: var(--neutral-white);
}


/* body mobile responsive */

@media screen and (max-width: 375px) {
  .main-content-container {
    margin-top: 0;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .img-gallary-container {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .img-gallary {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .large-img img {
    border-radius: 0;
  }
  .product-info-container {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .product-info {
    padding: 0 1rem;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .general-description h1 {
    font-size: 2rem;
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
  }
  .smaller-images {
    display: none;
  }
  .shopping-cart-overlay {
    position: fixed;
    left: 10px;
    right: 10px;
    top: 80px;
  }
  .buttons-container {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .amount-buttons {
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
  }
  .add-to-cart-button {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 1rem 0;
  }
  .arrow-left {
    display: flex;
  }
  .arrow-right {
    display: flex;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Frontend Mentor | Sneakers</title>

  <!-- css -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/main.css">

  <!-- fontawesome -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.0.0-beta3/css/all.min.css" />

  <!-- js -->
  <script src="./js/script.js" defer></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="page-container">

    <!-- overlay -->
    <div class="overlay" id="overlay"></div>

    <!-- header -->
    <header>

      <div class="left-container">
        <div class="logo-container">
          <i class="fas fa-bars" id="hamburger-menu"></i>
          <img src="./images/logo.svg" alt="logo">
        </div>
        <nav id="nav">
          <ul>
            <i class="fas fa-times" id="mobile-close-button"></i>
            <li><a href="#">Collections</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Men</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Women</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>

      <div class="right-container">
        <div class="account-container">
          <div class="shopping-cart-overlay" id="shopping-cart">
            <div class="shopping-cart-header">
              <h4>Cart</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="shopping-cart-content" id="item-list">
              <p id="empty-cart">Your cart is empty</p>
              <button class="checkout-button" id="checkout-button"><h4>Checkout</h4></button>
            </div>
          </div>
          <a href="#" class="cart-icon-container" id="cart-button">
            <img src="./images/icon-cart.svg" alt="cart">
          </a>
          <img class="avatar" src="./images/image-avatar.png" alt="profile-pic">
        </div>
      </div>

    </header>

    <!-- main content -->
    <div class="main-content-container">

      <!-- img gallary -->
      <div class="img-gallary-container">
        <div class="img-gallary">
          <div class="large-img">
            <img id="large-img" src="./images/image-product-1-thumbnail-HR.jpg" alt="">
            <div class="arrow-left" id="arrow-left">
              <i class="fas fa-chevron-left"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="arrow-right" id="arrow-right">
              <i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="smaller-images">
            <img id="pic" src="./images/image-product-1-thumbnail.jpg" alt="img-1">
            <img id="pic" src="./images/image-product-2-thumbnail.jpg" alt="img-2">
            <img id="pic" src="./images/image-product-3-thumbnail.jpg" alt="img-3">
            <img id="pic" src="./images/image-product-4-thumbnail.jpg" alt="img-4">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- product info -->
      <div class="product-info-container">
        <div class="product-info">
          <div class="general-description">
            <h3>Sneaker company</h3>
            <h1>Fall limited edition <br> sneakers</h1>
            <p>
              These low-profile sneakers are your perfect casual wear companion. Featuring a durable rubber outer sole, they'll withstand everything the weather can offer.
            </p>
          </div>
          <div class="price-container">
            <div class="price">
              <h2 id="discount-price">$125.00</h2>
              <h4 class="discount">50%</h4>
            </div>
            <h4 id="original-price">$250.00</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="buttons-container">
            <div class="amount-buttons">
              <button id="remove-button">
                <i class="fas fa-minus"></i>
              </button>
              <h2 id="amount-value">0</h2>
              <button id="add-button">
                <i class="fas fa-plus"></i>
              </button>
            </div>
            <button class="add-to-cart-button" id="add-to-cart">
              <svg width="22" height="20" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                <path d="M20.925 3.641H3.863L3.61.816A.896.896 0 0 0 2.717 0H.897a.896.896 0 1 0 0 1.792h1l1.031 11.483c.073.828.52 1.726 1.291 2.336C2.83 17.385 4.099 20 6.359 20c1.875 0 3.197-1.87 2.554-3.642h4.905c-.642 1.77.677 3.642 2.555 3.642a2.72 2.72 0 0 0 2.717-2.717 2.72 2.72 0 0 0-2.717-2.717H6.365c-.681 0-1.274-.41-1.53-1.009l14.321-.842a.896.896 0 0 0 .817-.677l1.821-7.283a.897.897 0 0 0-.87-1.114ZM6.358 18.208a.926.926 0 0 1 0-1.85.926.926 0 0 1 0 1.85Zm10.015 0a.926.926 0 0 1 0-1.85.926.926 0 0 1 0 1.85Zm2.021-7.243-13.8.81-.57-6.341h15.753l-1.383 5.53Z" fill="#fff" fill-rule="nonzero"/>
              </svg>
              <h4>Add to cart</h4>
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>

  </div>

</body>

</html>
```